# is it possible to use a `WITH` clause in a DataWindow query?

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder, datawindow, with-clause

I have a DataWindow in a PB10.5 application which works perfectly until I add a `WITH` clause to the top of the SQL query that sits behind. The query painter accepts it as valid syntax, and if I manually retrieve the data in the DataWindow painter, it works perfectly there too. The problem comes when running the application where the retrieve consistently returns -1. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: That's interesting. I have the opposite problem with CTEs using PowerBuilder and DB2. In the DB Painter, the SQL won't return data (no errors, just no data). But if I put the SQL in a datawindow and run it from code it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look what returns `sqlca.sqlerrtext` (providing that the current object transaction is the default `sqlca`, you may need to adapt that) just after the `-1` return by `retrieve()` it should help.

You could also put a breakpoint into the DW `dberror()` event to look if there is something useful here in case of error.

Comment: There's nothing in `sqlerrtext` :-(

Comment: @ninesided: Obviously, -1 for `retrieve()` means there is a problem. Did you checked that the `retrieve()` is not overloaded or wrapped in something that is performing a `commit` or `rollback` that could reset the error text from the DBMS? Also just added a point about `dberror` in my answer.

Comment: `dberror()` was a good shout, there's a sneaky hidden ORA-00942 getting returned from the DB that was being gobbled. Not exactly sure why it is being raised, yet but I've at least got a direction to look in. Thank you!